# Find a particular function given certain restrictions

Tags: elementary-number-theory, cryptography

This maybe more of a computer science problem but maybe the solution lies in number theory.

Given integers $x,y$, define a function $f$ so that

$$f(x,y) =
\begin{cases}
1  & \text{if $x=y$} \\
0 & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
$$

The obvious solution Negate( $x-y$ ) cannot be applied. The reason is that $f$ needs to operate on homomorphically encrypted integers, and negation is not homomorphic.

Comment: If you are allowed to use integer division (division with remainder ignored), how about $(x/y)(y/x)$?  As long as $x,y>0$ of course.

Comment: Perhaps reveal to us what $x$ and $y$ are supposed to be... real numbers, $p$-adic numbers, negative integers, ... what?

Comment: CEdgar: x,y are integers (sorry I omitted that)

Comment: Perhaps also reveal to us what operations *are* allowed?